# Writing textFields/textArea to text file

Tags: java, swing, file-io, textarea, textfield

So in the applet I'm making I need the values from my two text fields and my text area written to a text file upon pressing the submit button. The Text is being read just fine, but it is not recording to the text document.

`nameField` and `topicField` are my two text fields, and `paragraphArea` is my text area. Topics.txt is the blank text file I have in my Java package.

```
   JButton submitButton = new JButton("SUBMIT");
    submitButton.setSize(100, 30);
    submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            String name = nameField.getText();
            String topic = topicField.getText();
            String paragraph = paragraphArea.getText();


            String fileWrite = "Topics.txt";

            try {
                FileWriter fileWriter =
                    new FileWriter(fileWrite);

                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =
                    new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

                bufferedWriter.newLine();
                bufferedWriter.write(name);
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
                bufferedWriter.write(topic);
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
                bufferedWriter.write(paragraph);
                bufferedWriter.newLine();

                bufferedWriter.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(
                    "Error writing to file '"
                    + fileWrite + "'");
            }

        }
     });
add(submitButton);
}
}
```

I really don't see what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I figured out what the problem was, it was recording to the bin folder copy of the topics document, not the src.

Comment: does the exeption get thrown?

Comment: Try creating a new Java.File instance with the textfile, then using that in the constructor for FileWriter.

File outputFile = new File(fileWrite);  FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);

Comment: Not at all. The console is blank, and I already tested with some System.out.prinln's, it is definitely reading the textfields and areas.

Comment: @Dimfish This works on my machine, is Topics.txt definately in the root directory?

Comment: It is in there, I double checked and even made a new one. Going to try Mattee's applet privilege suggestion.

Comment: Alright so giving it privilege didn't do anything. This is really perplexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine, it was just reading and writing in different places.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try {
    FileWriter fileWriter =
        new FileWriter(fileWrite);

    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =
        new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    bufferedWriter.write(name);
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    bufferedWriter.write(topic);
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    bufferedWriter.write(paragraph);
    bufferedWriter.newLine();

    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error writing to file '"
                + fileWrite + "'");
    }
    finally {
        if (bufferedWriter != null) {
            bufferedWriter.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a print writer instead of a file writer and bufferedWriter.

```
        try {
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter("Topics.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Then to save to file, just use 'println'

```
printWriter.println(name);
printWriter.println(topic);
printWriter.println(paragraph);

printWriter.close();
```

I'm not sure if PrintWriter or FileWriter is better, but PrintWriter worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Is is possible that this is because your application is an applet? There is an Oracle page [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) that says the following about applets: "They cannot access client resources such as the local filesystem, executable files, system clipboard, and printers."

If this is the case, I think you may need a privileged applet.